# Ubuntu Studio 23.04 - Autologin doesn't work

Tags: boot, startup, auto-login, sddm

Using the default login manager / greeter (sddm) which seems to support both X11 and Wayland. However i have to type my password at each startup, despite trying every way i can think of to get my session to start automatically on boot. Makes no difference which desktop/WM i last used: KDE (default), icewm etc.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 is a *released product*, with Ubuntu *mantic* being the *alpha* or *beta* product, and it being renamed from Ubuntu *mantic* to Ubuntu 23.04 when it reached RC status (what follows *beta*).  If you're still using the *beta* then please upgrade packages asap as that maybe related to your issue, otherwise you're using Ubuntu Studio 23.04 and not a *beta* thus question needs editing.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/04/20/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-released/

Comment: Modifying `sddm` to autologin is covered in many places; ie. disabling in the Lubuntu manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.8/sddm_configuration.html) or enabling it in questions (https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/set-lubuntu-to-autologin-after-installation/3981) but I'd first check what you're using... ie. *beta* highlights you're months behind on security fixes & that is your major issue as I see it.  (`sddm` is shared by Kubuntu, Lubuntu & Ubuntu Studio with all the same in this regard)

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the info in both your above comments. The installation process did have an option to have auto-login enabled by default, it might be some left-over ubuntu stuff that's not shared by K, L, and Studio? Also, i don't need to reinstall the OS to apply the new beta->RCx/current changes? That machine is pretty up to date with what's shown in the repositories.

Comment: If your machine is *pretty yo to date* then it's not *beta* and won't have been since 13 April 2023 (see https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-schedule/27284 where RC replaced *beta*) thus correct post; as using *beta* implies your system is **very behind** on security fixes & packages.  FYI:  Ubuntu Studio & Lubuntu both share QA of the installer, as we both use the same `calamares`....   If you applied all security fixes you'll be using 23.04 & `lsb_release -a` will say so, eg. `Description:    Ubuntu Mantic Minotaur (development branch)` on a *alpha* or *beta* for *mantic*

Comment: If you were still using 23.04 *beta* you'd see `Description:    Ubuntu Lunar Lobster (development branch)` and not 23.04  (same occurs with *alpha* & *beta*... it changed to 23.04 when it reached RC or *Release Candidate* in the final *days* before release of Ubuntu 23.04 (& all *flavors*)